# Visual / Practical / Real World Example for variable assignment in Javascript with different type

Tags: javascript

Want to understand how variable works in javascript when different type of values assigned to them.

- Type 1: String Boolean Number
- Type 2: Array Objects Functions Regex Date

Currently referring two books which are causing confusion.

```
let mood = "light";
console.log(mood);
// → light
mood = "dark";
console.log(mood);
// → dark
```

> You should imagine bindings as tentacles, rather than boxes. They do not
>   contain values; they grasp them—two bindings can refer to the same value.
>   A program can access only the values that it still has a reference to. When
>   you need to remember something, you grow a tentacle to hold on to it or you
>   reattach one of your existing tentacles to it.

And

> We saw that object values can be modified. The types of values discussed in
>   earlier chapters, such as numbers, strings, and Booleans, are all immutable—it
>   is impossible to change values of those types. You can combine them and derive
>   new values from them, but when you take a specific string value, that value
>   will always remain the same. The text inside it cannot be changed. If you
>   have a string that contains "cat", it is not possible for other code to change a
>   character in your string to make it spell "rat".

From [Eloquent Javascript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/Eloquent_JavaScript.pdf)

---

> JavaScript lets you give names to values using variables. You can
>   think of a variable as a box that you can fit one thing in. If you put
>   something else in it, the first thing goes away

Further

> Cool! The value of the variable isn’t set in stone, though
>   (they’re called variables because they can vary), and if you want
>   to update it, just use = again:

From: [Javascript for Kids](https://nostarch.com/javascriptforkids)

Different authors suggest different imagination to understand concepts. Apart from boxes, tentacles is there any example which can help me to get the context.
Need to understand what is getting stored in variable (values/address/ binary representation of values). Is there any video, images resource which clarify core concepts.

Having such views how to answer such questions (variables of string type changed with other values) as interviewer can also have different way of their own understanding

Comment: Base on my opinion I think the later was best suitable to distinguished the variable assignment in javascript. They are container/box that holds data and when assigned to a new data the old data is removed and the new one is inserted. But that's only my opinion.

Comment: @Francisaskquestion well, when you will go deeper to js, you will discover, that variables can not only be boxes itself, but *conductors* - the change of variable can trigger some side effects) But basically - yes, you are right

Comment: @Levitator, yeah you are right, they can be conductors. Well it's better than tentacles.

Answer (score 1):

Well after reading many sources in the internet, mostly they treat the variable as container but the variable itself in not the data.
See in [Storing the information you need — Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables). They said that

> We say variables contain values. This is an important distinction to make. Variables aren't the values themselves; they are containers for values. You can think of them being like little cardboard boxes that you can store things in.

And also in W3Schools [JavaScript Variables](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp), They also state that

> JavaScript variables are containers for storing data values.

So, in my conclusion the most Visual / Practical / Real World Example for variable assignment in Javascript with different type are imagining it as a box.